# Count and group by operation with two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

| Movieid | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Toy Story |
| 2 | Jumanji |
| 2 | Jumanji |
| 1 | Toy Story |

### Second Table

| Movieid | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |

I have two tables with several columns like this.

My problem statement is

--Show top-rated movies with movieid and movie name (number of rating for certain movie should be greater than 200, print it in decreasing order)

I was trying like this, but I am having error like

> Column 'vtopmovie.movieid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

```
create view vtopmovie as
select m.movieid, m.title, r.rating from movies m, ratings r
where m.movieid=r.movieid

select * from vtopmovie

select top(200) movieid, sum(rating) from vtopmovie
group by title
```

So, what could be the best possible query for this?

Comment: In select list you've used movieid but data is group by with title...that's why error occured...either use both title, movieid in select list and group by or non aggregated column/s in select list must be placed in group by clause.

Comment: See [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) you really should have kicked by now

Comment: Still not getting it, could anyone please help?

Comment: Your last query should be `GROUP BY movieid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should like this if you want to get movieid and movie name with its rating

```
select top(200) movieid, title, sum(rating) from vtopmovie
group by movieid, title
```